# Is there a way to detect XmlHttpRequest cannot resolve URL?

Tags: xmlhttprequest

Is there a way to detect XmlHttpRequest cannot resolve URL ? It seem no exception are throw when calling Open(...) with a bad url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTTP Status Code would be zero.
This applies to network problems where connection can't be established and no proxy is used.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably get a 404 not found header returned.

Comment: Nope i don't get anything not even 404.